# how to move newsletter block from footer to left in magento

Tags: newsletter, footer

Originally, I had the newsletter block in the footer, this is code:

```
<div>{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}</div>
```

I then pasted the above code into the left column instead. After this, I deleted it from the footer but, it is still persisting in footer for some reason.

How do I remove the newsletter block from the footer, since deleting it didn't seem to remove it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `app/design/frontend/theme/theme/layout/newsletter.xml` change from:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="newsletter" before="footer_store_language" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

To:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" before="-" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Try clearing cache, and reindexing

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It's worked. you are a genius. thanks a lot.

Comment: Please verify the answer if it worked.

Comment: Hi,  Sorry for late verify. I went for vacation.Thanks a lot again.

Comment: check this link it's reference of all magneto default block name that can you remove any time.http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/05/remove-default-magneto-block-like-news.html

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this will be cache issue. Magento will cache footer section. So removing entire cache would solve this problem

Remove entire cache my removing entires inside `var/cache`

or

Try it through admin `System > Cache Management > Flush Cache Storage`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by direct php call.Create block  `programmatically` of type  `newsletter/subscribe`  and set it template

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call to app\design\frontend\default\yourTheme\layout\page.xml

```
<block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
```

Call to Footer.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter'); ?>
```